# Weblogic 12 with no web.xml webapp

Tags: weblogic, spring-4

Is it possible to create a Spring Web Mvc App without web.xml [already done and deploy successfully in TOMCAT 8] and deploy Weblogic 12.

Steps :
1) Used maven-archetype-webapp.
2) Deleted the generated web.xml and index.html.
3) Below are the java config files:

```
package com.test.xyz.config;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class TestInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        Filter [] singleton = { new CORSFilter() };
        return singleton;
    }   

}
```

/**Second*****/

```
package com.test.xyz.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.test.xyz"},
excludeFilters={
@Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)
})
public class RootConfig {
}
```

/****THIRD*****/

```
package com.test.xyz.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
/**
 * All the beans configured here will be loaded under dispatcher-servlet 
 * application context
 */
@Configuration
/**
 * @EnableWebMvc is replacement for <mvc:annotation-driven>
 */
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.test.xyz")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    /**
     * @config JSP view resolver
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =
    new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    return resolver;
    }

    /**
     * @handle request for static resources 
     * otherwise dispatcher-servlet need to do it
     * here you are forwarding request to servlet container’s 
     * default servlet
     */


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/standardversion/**").addResourceLocations("/standardversion/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in weblogic in resolving WebApplicationInitializer subclasses. If you add redundant interface WebApplicationInitializer to your TestConfig it should work.

So you TestConfig should look like this..

```
public class TestInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
...... your code ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be feasible.

web.xml is mandatory for 2.5 and 3.0+ is not necessary (optional).

if it works in Tomcat then it will work in WLS (web container)

Comment: Didn't work, once I added the web.xml in same project, it started coming up. Before it was giving - HTTP 403 'Forbidden'. I have added the steps I used  above. Please let me know if I am missing anything.